# Comparar dos string en Dart?

Tags: flutter, condiciones, dart

Intentando comparar un string que esta como objeto con una cadena de texto que el usuario ingresa en una pantalla de inicio de sesion, si el usuario ingresa como asesor  lo lleva a un pantalla1 y si ingresa con otro nombre lo lleva a pantalla2, se intenta hacer esto con  la condicional if-else

```
String usuario= "asesor";
String nombre;

If ( nombre == usuario) {...}
```

Comment: Cuál es la pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Si usas un `TextField` te sugiero usar un `TextEditingController` que esto lo declaras al principio de tu clase:

```
final controllerNombre = TextEditingController();
  //en el ejemplo solo nos importa el cargo
  final controllerCargo = TextEditingController();
  final controllerContrasena = TextEditingController();
```

Supongamos que tienes el formulario de inicio de sesión, usuario, cargo y contraseña(a cada textfield le asignas su controlador):

```
Column(
  children: [
    TextField(
      controller: controllerNombre,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Ingrese el cargo", label: Text("cargo")),
    ),
    TextField(
      controller: controllerCargo,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Ingrese su nombre", label: Text("nombre")),
    ),
    TextField(
      controller: controllerContrasena,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Ingrese la contraseña", label: Text("contraseña")),
    )
  ],
);
```

Ahora para poder hacer la valicación supongamos que tenemos un botón debajo del formulario, este botón se encargara de hacer la validación que necesitas para dirigir a la pantalla que desees:

```
    TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            //tienes la opcion de usar Switch case o if else, me gusta mas el switch pero ya es decisión tuya
            switch (controllerCargo.text) {
              // Si lo que ingresaste en el campo "cargo" es igual a una de las opciones a continuación, irá a la pagina ya establecida
              case "asesor":
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder) => PaginaAsesor()));
                break;
              case "admin":
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder) => PaginaAdmin()));
                break;
              case "usuario":
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder) => PaginaUsuario()));
                break;
              default:
            }
          },
          child: Text("Continuar"),
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.black),
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```